# Object array filtering problem in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have an Object.

```
export class Branch {
 id: string;
 name: string;
 location: string;
}
```

I initialized Branch object using

```
branchList: Branch[] = [];
```

Then I call a function with a branch object. For example like the following one,

```
filteringBranch(branch: Branch) {
 this.branchList = this.branchList.filter( item =>
      item.id !== branch.id &&
      item.name !== branch.name
 );
}
```

`This.branchList` should contain only those Branches whose id **and** name is not same on parameter branch's id **and** name. But in my code, it contains whose id **or** name is matched. Now What is the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the branch list filtered which does not match the parameter branch's id **or** name, am I correct?

Comment: No @Royson, branch list filtered which does not match the parameter branch's id and name.

Comment: In that case replace the `&&` with `||` or use the following condition `!(item.id == branch.id && item.name === branch.name)`. When `id` and `name` both match the value will be filtered out from the list.